# M-x run-python to get a Ipython shell in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

When `M-x run-python` it prompts a standard python shell

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
>>> clear
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'clear' is not defined
>>> import os
>>> os.system('clear')
256
```

[image]

I need a Ipython Shell and reference to documentation of `run-python` but get no clues.

How could get a Ipython shell after running `run-python`

Comment: Set the variable `python-shell-interpreter` to `"ipython"`

Comment: yes, but it report error `

WARNING: your terminal doesn’t support cursor position requests (CPR).` @Barmar

Comment: Did you follow the other directions in the linked question?

Comment: Copied the total 11 lines of setq and get the above error prompt @Barmar

Comment: How about the part after "ipython>=5 has a auto-complete feature which breaks the emacs sub-shell,", did you do that?

Comment: I appreciate it huge deeply your kindness, ty, it works lol @Barmar